# Regenerate thumbs in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I try to regenerate thumbs in PrestaShop™ 1.5.6.0 because of watermark. I have more than 6000 products. After the process I have got 90 errors like this:

Original image is missing or empty (.../domain/web/img/p/3/4/5/8/3458.jpg)

Images really don't exist.

Could someone help me?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This worked for me:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24044141/prestashop-1-6-upgrade-images-question-mark/24051513#24051513

Answer (score 0):

Probably a problem with the size of the images you upload. Try to resize them to below 1000x1000 before you upload. This might also be possible to resolve by changing the memory limit on the server.

Maybe you afterwards need to regenerate thubmnails using "images" > "regenerate thumbnails"