# PrestaShop 1.6 Upgrade, Images Question Mark

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I've upgraded my prestashop installation from 1.4 to 1.6 successfully with only 1 side effect.

The product images are now questions marks. http://prestastore.webdirective.com/catalog/

Ive already tried a few forums but no fix. I need help where to start checking. Im fairly new to prestashop so be elaborate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are few approaches for solving this problem:

1. Try regenerating the .htaccess file (BackOffice > Preferences > SEO & URLs > [Save])
2. Try regenerating the images (BackOffice > Preferences > Images > [Regenerate thumbnails])

Comment: A remark: generating thumbnails can take a lot of hours depending on the number of images you have. Try to choose the good moment to do it.

Comment: Im getting this errors when I regen the thumbs. "Original image is missing or empty ([...]/img/p/3/6/36.jpg) for product ID 9"

Comment: The error message is pretty clear - the original product image is missing. Regeneration can't do much if the image is physically not there.

Comment: I think the image folder has changed in 1.6? If so whats the path? I can probably get the images from my backup and paste it there. Im pretty sure the images were working before the upgrade though.